# Understanding HttpClient's Network Telemetry Data

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HttpClient to send GET requests to an external API in a C# application. I have noticed a small percentage of requests take longer than 10 seconds to complete. After looking at the network telemetry data for these long response requests. I see something like this.

```
02:33:56.8879787 System.Net.Http.RequestStart
02:33:56.8881421 System.Net.Http.RequestHeadersStart()
02:33:56.8881679 System.Net.Http.RequestHeadersStop()
02:33:58.0896207 System.Net.Sockets.AcceptStop()
02:33:58.0897726 System.Net.Sockets.AcceptStart(address:x)
02:34:01.0904942 System.Net.Sockets.AcceptStop()
02:34:01.0906336 System.Net.Sockets.AcceptStart(address:x)
02:34:04.0902032 System.Net.Sockets.AcceptStop()
02:34:07.0899629 System.Net.Sockets.AcceptStart(address:x)
02:34:12.4359057 System.Net.Http.ResponseHeadersStart()
```

A normal response time looks something like this

```
02:34:40.3426222 System.Net.Http.RequestStart(address:x)
02:34:40.3427601 System.Net.Http.RequestHeadersStart()
02:34:40.3427905 System.Net.Http.RequestHeadersStop()
02:34:40.5152574 System.Net.Http.ResponseHeadersStart()
02:34:40.3427905 System.Net.Http.RequestHeadersStop()
02:34:40.5153953 System.Net.Http.ResponseContentStart()
02:34:40.5154164 System.Net.Http.ResponseContentStop()
02:34:40.5154300 System.Net.Http.RequestStop()
```

Any idea what could be a source of the problem with all these accept start and accept stop messages?

Comment: Use a tool like Wireshark to observe the TCP traffic between the endpoints. That should clue you in about what those AcceptStart/AcceptStop events are related to. Going with quite a bit of tea-leaves reading, maybe this is part of a handshake, like for example the TLS/SSL handshake for HTTPS requests? Depending on whether you like to drink tea, you might find my speculation either more or less plausible...

Comment: Did you compare data to "normal" request? (while such thing seems to be the common sense to do it is extremely uncommon for people to look at "normal" traffic or behavior... and then try to attribute the problem to something that happen all the time...)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I just added what the logs look like with a normal response time

Comment: @Zach compare the responses, not the logs. The logs tell you that some responses take too long, not what they contained. Perhaps they're too big? Or there's TLS or authentication handshaking going on? `Socket.AcceptStop` and `Start` are network operations. Use a debugging proxy like Fiddler to see what's actually going on in each case